# Skeleton animation ThreeJs from Collada does not work

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, collada

I have this function to run animations but I got

> could not find the skeleton for the skin!

Actually I use Clara io to transform from fbx to collada when the fbx is animated and I detect if collada is aimated by frames or skeleton. I have issues to animate when is about skeleton

```
 function loadObjectAnimatedFrames(){
         console.log("Loading Object Frames Animated");
         var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
         loader.load( modelPath.val(), function ( collada ) {
            model = collada.scene;
            animations = collada.animations;
            kfAnimationsLength = animations.length;

            var box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject( model );
             setConfigObject(model,box);
             activeModel = model;
             objControl = new THREE.TransformControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
             objControl.addEventListener( 'change', render );
             objControl.setSize( .1);
             objControl.attach( model );
             scene.add( objControl );

            for ( var i = 0; i < kfAnimationsLength; ++i ) {
               var animation = animations[ i ];
               var kfAnimation = new THREE.KeyFrameAnimation( animation );
               kfAnimation.timeScale = 1;
               kfAnimations.push( kfAnimation );
            }
            start();
            animateFrames( lastTimestamp );
            scene.add( model );
         });
      }
```